# Difference between k means and c means

Tags: java, algorithm, k-means, fuzzy-c-means

I m trying to implement the k-means algorithm so i need to know what is the difference in the algorithm for k means and c means? 
 Are they same with different names or is there any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345903/whats-is-the-difference-between-k-means-and-fuzzy-c-means-objective-function) given by @Reed Copsey in one of the Stackoverflow question. You will surely find your response:-

> The main difference is that, in Fuzzy-C Means clustering, each point
>   has a weighting associated with a particular cluster, so a point
>   doesn't sit "in a cluster" as much as has a weak or strong association
>   to the cluster, which is determined by the inverse distance to the
>   center of the cluster.
>
> Fuzzy-C means will tend to run slower than K means, since it's
>   actually doing more work. Each point is evaluated with each cluster,
>   and more operations are involved in each evaluation. K-Means just
>   needs to do a distance calculation, whereas fuzzy c means needs to do
>   a full inverse-distance weighting.